# Why just starting the Django development server fail with "keywords must be strings"?

Tags: python, django

I'm starting to learn Django and have been following the online tutorial on the Django website.

Everything was working fine and I have a folder called mysite and then sub folders called mysite/ and manage.py like it says in the tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project

However when I run the command

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

I get this:

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x10165aed0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
self._populate()
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 72, in _populate
self.load_app(app_name, True)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
models = import_module('.models', app_name)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 21, in <module>
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 127, in <module>
class ContentType(models.Model):
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 97, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
__init__() keywords must be strings
```

According to the tutorial it should say this:

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
April 14, 2013 - 15:50:53
Django version 1.5, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

I've tried to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in my web browser but I just get te error cant connect.

Does anybody know where I am going wrong or what I need to do to rectify the issue?

I'm using Django 1.5 and Python 2.6.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/#install-python):

> Django 1.5 works with any Python version from 2.6.5 to 2.7.

And according to [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18961), I would suggest you to upgrade your Python version. Or, if you can't upgrade it, you have another way, which is presented in the [last comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18961#comment:6) of the ticket:

> Use Django 1.4, which supports Python 2.5+