# Django: runserver won't work

Tags: python, django

I have installed and created a project by following the DjangoProject tutorial.
Everything works fine, I checked that Django is installed by typing import django on the Python command-lines.

However, when I type python manager.py runserver, it won't work. I haven't edited any file and followed the tutorial step by step, so I really don't see what's wrong.

Here is the error I get:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of    <    django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x101115fd0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",     line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in     validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 72, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 21, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 127, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 97, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    __init__() keywords must be strings
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your `model.py` file here.

Comment: seems like exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998882/django-development-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538398/following-the-first-django-app-tutorial-and-i-cant-execute-the-runserver-comman

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you are using a version of Python earlier than 2.6.5, with the latest Django version. Django 1.5 is only compatible with Python 2.6.5+. You should upgrade Python, or use Django 1.4.

Comment: You're right, I'm now using Python 3.3 and it works. Thank you very much!